# Python Matplotlib- chart can't update itself

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make graph that would plot real time stock prices. My code is shown below.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import time

t = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/YHOO/history?ltr=1')
the = t.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(the, 'html.parser')
timeticks = []
x = []
prices = []
i = 1

while 1:    

    n = soup.find('span',class_="Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px)")     
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.cla()
    nf = float(n.string)
    prices.append(nf)

    now= datetime.datetime.now()
    times=('%02d:%02d:%d'%(now.hour,now.minute,now.second))
    timeticks.append(times)
    x.append(i)

    plt.xticks(x,timeticks)
    plt.plot(x,prices,"b-")
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Stock prices")
    plt.title("Yahoo's Stocks")
    plt.show()
    i +=1
```

When I run the code, I get a figure and when I close it, another figure with another plotted point shows up. What I want to do is keep the first figure update it for every point shown every one second. Is there a way to do this? (By the way, I do know that there is a yahoo finance package. Before I finished this much of my code, I didn't know, so I used Bs4.)